# I am trying to add an object key value to an empty array using a a for loop to filter, I keep getting an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  let matchingCampsites = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false) {
      if (campgrounds[i].view === view) {
        if (campgrounds[i].partySize <= partySize) {
             matchingCampsites.push(campgrounds[i].number)
        } 
        return matchingCampsites
      } else {
        return "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party"
      }
    }
  }
     
}

const campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];
```

I tried removing .number in the push statement, that didn't work, I get the right message when nothing matches and returns "Sorry no campsites......" but get back an empty array for everything else

Comment: You're returning in the first iteration of the loop, even if you haven't added anything to the array.

Comment: And you return the error before going through the entire array.

Comment: Also... don't you want to find Campgrounds that have a partySize >= the search criteria not <=. ?

Comment: so it kinda worked, for findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 4)) I got [5] instead of [1,5], findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'forest', 3) I got "Sorry no campsites....."  instead of [18] and for findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'desert', 2) it returned the expected output of "Sorry, no campsites......

Answer (score 2):

You need to return after the loop is done, not inside the loop.

```js
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  let matchingCampsites = []

  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false) {
      if (campgrounds[i].view === view) {
        if (campgrounds[i].partySize <= partySize) {
          matchingCampsites.push(campgrounds[i].number)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  if (matchingCampsites.length == 0) {
    return "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party"
  } else {
    return matchingCampsites;
  }
}
```

It would probably be better if the caller checked the length and reported the error, rather than returning a string instead of an array in that case. Or the function could throw an exception.